# QML - Move to top #TOP

Tags: qt, qml, flickable

I am using a `Flickable` which is embedded in a Rectangle.
There is a button in the bottom of the rectangle.
My requirement is when I press the button my Flickable will move to top.
Its almost like #TOP in HTML.
Is anybody have an idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to set Flickable's [contentY](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qml-flickable.html#contentY-prop) property to 0.